# Remove file extension in root & folders

Tags: .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

How may I do so it removes the extension from all the files in the directories as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `[^/]*` to `.+`. So that it will also match against the `/` character.

Then replace:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
```

with

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
```

Comment: I get server error. "The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script."

Comment: @user3740791 sorry, replace the `[^/]*` with `.+`